# Append to a string shortened by text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'd like to cleanly display a string shortened by an ellipsis in quotation marks for example, the string a long sentence that shouldn't be fully displayed shown as `"a long sentence..."`.

However, when I use the ellipsis provided by text-overflow: it will render as `"a long sentence... "`.  What may be done to remove the extra space included in the ellipsis?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Probably whitespace between some tags.

Answer (score 1):

Example taken straight from here: [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

I removed the padding on paragraphs. As you can see there is no "extra space"

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;

  /* BOTH of the following are required for text-overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-visible {
  white-space: initial;
}

.overflow-clip {
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.overflow-ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.overflow-string {
  /* Not supported in most browsers, 
     see the 'Browser compatibility' section below */
  text-overflow: " [..]"; 
}
```

```html
<p class="overflow-visible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<p class="overflow-clip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<p class="overflow-ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<p class="overflow-string">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```